# Error with CryptoJS in ASP.NET Core Application - Can't find variable: CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, encryption, cryptojs

I'm trying to used `CryptoJS` to encrypt the login username and password, I always getting the error `Can't find variable: CryptoJS`, Here's the steps that I follow:

1. Include the `ads.js` file in `js` folder in wwwroot directory.
2. Include `AESEncryption.cs` to the project.
3. added  `<script src="~/js/aes.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` to the end of `_Layout.cshtml` page.
4. Using the following function in `Index.cshtml`

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">

   function CheckData()

   {
       var txtUserName = $('#Username').val();
       var txtpassword = $('#Password').val();

       if (txtUserName == "") {
           alert('Please enter UserName');
           return false;
       }
       else if (txtpassword == "") {
           alert('Please enter Password');
           return false;
       }
       else {

           var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('8080808080808080');
           var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('8080808080808080');

           var encryptedlogin = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(txtUserName), key,
               { keySize: 128 / 8, iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 });
           $('#Username').val(encryptedlogin);

           var encryptedpassword = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(txtpassword), key,
               { keySize: 128 / 8, iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 });
           $('#Password').val(encryptedpassword);
       }
   }
   ```

I always getting **Can't find variable: CryptoJS**

This is a sample application that contain the problem [HERE](https://www.4shared.com/zip/ZsdpQxyjea/Main-Solution.html)

Comment: Are you calling `CheckData()` immediately when the page loads or on an event like a button click? IF you want to share code with us, please use github or a  similar platform. I wont download an archive from an untrusted source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following `aes.js`,and it can work.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
```

Here is a demo:

```
<input id="Username" />
<input id="Password" />
<button onclick="CheckData()">check</button>
@section scripts
{
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
    <script>
        function CheckData() {
            var txtUserName = $('#Username').val();
            var txtpassword = $('#Password').val();

            if (txtUserName == "") {
                alert('Please enter UserName');
                return false;
            }
            else if (txtpassword == "") {
                alert('Please enter Password');
                return false;
            }
            else {

                var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('8080808080808080');
                var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('8080808080808080');

                var encryptedlogin = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(txtUserName), key,
                    { keySize: 128 / 8, iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 });
                $('#Username').val(encryptedlogin);

                var encryptedpassword = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(txtpassword), key,
                    { keySize: 128 / 8, iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 });
                $('#Password').val(encryptedpassword);
            }
        }
}
```

result:
[image]